# I want to remove certain characters in list in python

Tags: python, parsing

This is the list I have :

```
[('11 August 1902\xa0(1902-08-11)Paris, France', None), 
 ('29 July 1991(1991-07-29) (aged\xa088)Paris, France', None), 
 ('\xa0France', None), ('\xa0French Army', None), ('1921-1959', None), 
 ('General de brigade', None), 
 ('Mobile Group 2Mobile Group 1Operational Group North-West', None),
 ('World War IIFirst Indochina War*Battle of Dien Bien Phu', None)]
```

I want to remove `None` and `'\xa0'` from the list.

My friend said I would need to convert it into a string to remove the text and convert it back into a list. If this is the only way how would I keep each item in the list separate from each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a (bad) example of how to achieve this... however a more elegant way would be to encode the strings as ISO 8859-1 (I think thats where the \xa0 comes from).

```
my_list = [('11 August 1902\xa0(1902-08-11)Paris, France', None), 
           ('29 July 1991(1991-07-29) (aged\xa088)Paris, France', None), 
           ('\xa0France', None),
           ('\xa0French Army', None),
           ('1921-1959', None), 
           ('General de brigade', None),
           ('Mobile Group 2Mobile Group 1Operational Group North-West', None),
           ('World War IIFirst Indochina War*Battle of Dien Bien Phu', None)]

my_new_list = []

for my_item in my_list:
    tuple_first = my_item[0]

    tuple_first = tuple_first.replace('\xa0', ' ') # I think really this should be
                                                   # encoded with the ISO 8859-1 and
                                                   # in this encoding \xa0 is a non
                                                   # breaking space... but for now
                                                   # I just replace it with a space char
    my_new_list.append(tuple_first)
```

and here is the output (new line per item)

```
['11 August 1902 (1902-08-11)Paris, France',
'29 July 1991(1991-07-29) (aged 88)Paris, France',
'France',
'French Army',
'1921-1959',
'General de brigade',
'Mobile Group 2Mobile Group 1Operational Group North-West',
'World War IIFirst Indochina War*Battle of Dien Bien Phu'
]
```

Comment: I tried this and i got back ['1', 'A', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'P', 'F', '2', 'J', '1', '1', '0', '2', 'a', '8', 'P', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'A', '1', '1', 'G', 'd', 'b', 'M', 'G', '2', 'G', '1', 'G', 'N', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'I', 'I', 'W', 'B', 'o', 'D', 'B', 'P']. I'm not sure where I went wrong

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to convert the list to a string (that would be one of the worst methods). You can simply use list comprehensions, for example:

```
>>> my_list = [
    ('11 August 1902\xa0(1902-08-11)Paris, France', None),
    ('29 July 1991(1991-07-29) (aged\xa088)Paris, France', None), 
    ('\xa0France', None), 
    ('\xa0French Army', None), 
    ('1921-1959', None), 
    ('General de brigade', None), 
    ('Mobile Group 2Mobile Group 1Operational Group North-West', None), 
    ('World War IIFirst Indochina War*Battle of Dien Bien Phu', None)]
>>> [t[0].replace('\xa0', ' ') for t in my_list]
['11 August 1902 (1902-08-11)Paris, France', '29 July 1991(1991-07-29) (aged 88)Paris, France', ' France', ' French Army', '1921-1959', 'General de brigade', 'Mobile Group 2Mobile Group 1Operational Group North-West', 'World War IIFirst Indochina War*Battle of Dien Bien Phu']
```

This will use the first element in each inner tuple (hence eliminating the second element which is `None`) and replacing any `\xa0` characters with a single space (`" "`) in it.

Comment: @Remmerton It is the loop variable. I changed it to `t` for better readability.

Comment: Are you sure you have a list to begin with? It looks like you have a string representation of a list instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to see the list comprehension provided by Selcuk.

**Note: Accept Selcuk's solution, as it is correct. I'm just posting this to show how the list comprehension works/looks compared to the `for` loop**

```
my_list = [('11 August 1902\xa0(1902-08-11)Paris, France', None), 
('29 July 1991(1991-07-29) (aged\xa088)Paris, France', None), 
('\xa0France', None), ('\xa0French Army', None), ('1921-1959', None), 
('General de brigade', None), ('Mobile Group 2Mobile Group 1Operational Group North-West', None),
 ('World War IIFirst Indochina War*Battle of Dien Bien Phu', None)]

new_list = []
for t in my_list:
    t = t[0].replace('\xa0',' ')
    new_list.append(t)
```

**Output:**

```
print (new_list)
['11 August 1902 (1902-08-11)Paris, France', '29 July 1991(1991-07-29) (aged 88)Paris, France', ' France', ' French Army', '1921-1959', 'General de brigade', 'Mobile Group 2Mobile Group 1Operational Group North-West', 'World War IIFirst Indochina War*Battle of Dien Bien Phu']
```

Comment: I tried that method but i got ['1', 'A', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'P', 'F', '2', 'J', '1', '1', '0', '2', 'a', '8', 'P', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'A', '1', '1', 'G', 'd', 'b', 'M', 'G', '2', 'G', '1', 'G', 'N', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'I', 'I', 'W', 'B', 'o', 'D', 'B', 'P'] back. Not sure why.

Comment: what list do you have that you're apply this to? Because it must be different than the one you supplied in the original question.. Your output is taking the first letter of each word, so it's iterating each individual string, not the first element of the tuple.

Comment: provide your full code. show me how you're generating that list.